# Mysqli query working in phpmyadmin but not on script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

My mysql query is `SELECT`ing all the rows that matched the query in phpMyAdmin (119 rows) but selecting only a few (6 rows) when it comes to php script.
Here's my code for phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM  Query WHERE status=0 && category!='edu' ORDER BY qtime ASC
```

And this is what I used in script

```
$sql= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  Query 
        WHERE status=0 && category!='edu' ORDER BY qtime ASC");
echo mysqli_num_rows($sql); //which is giving 6 always
```

So, clearly the connection is fine & there are no errors in running the query. Now, I couldn't figure out what is wrong actually. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you connected to the right database?  And have you triple checked that it is the case?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it many times and it is obvious right, Without connecting to the database, how could it even pull 6 rows!

Comment: @Vishwa: Sometimes programmers have a test database & a live database.  If that's the case with you, are you sure both your examples are connecting to the *same* database?

Comment: No, I haven't used any test database. I've only a single database on the server with a couple of tables.

Comment: @Vishwa - try removing the WHERE and see how many you get - does that match up with what you're seeing in your database?

Comment: @andrewsi, Yes, it did. I've 1603 rows in `Query` table, it gave me all the 1603 rows without `WHERE`. With `WHERE`, it is showing only last 6 results but there are 119 rows satisfying the condition given in `WHERE`.

Comment: @Vishwa - then try adding the conditions back in; try each separately and compare and contrast with the database result.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion @andrewsi. :) So, I figured that the problem is with `status`. When I ran `SELECT * FROM  Query WHERE status=0 ORDER BY qtime ASC` , it gave me only 22 rows but actually there are 137 rows. Now, how do I go further?

Comment: @Vishwa - you need to look at the rows that are showing up in your database, but not through your mysqli query. Presumably, they have something in their status field that PHPMyAdmin is interpreting as 0, but that mysqli isn't.

Comment: The field type for `status` was set to `INT`. And I update it with only 0's or 1's. So, here are the results:
With php script:
`WHERE status=0 => 6 rows
WHERE status=1=> 1597 rows`
phpMyAdmin:
`WHERE status=0 => 137 rows
WHERE status=1=> 1466 rows`
The sum is 1603 in both cases. So, I believe, this shows that there are only 0's &1's in `status` column

Answer (score 0):

Probably this may fix your problem:

```
`SELECT * FROM  Query WHERE status IN(0) AND category!='edu' ORDER BY qtime ASC;`
```

Comment: Thank you @Angel. There is an increment from 6 to 9 rows now. But, still the number it is too low. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try changing the STATUS Type to boolean in the database since you only use 1 and 0, otherwise use '', also try to use IN at category (this may be a longer code since you must put all posible values there.

Comment: Finally, It is clear that the issue is not with 0's & 1's. I've changed it to boolean, but still getting the same results.
Now, the problem is clearly with `status`.